# Assets not deploying with Jekyll / Jekyll / Siteleaf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm new to Jekyll/Siteleaf and trying to understand why the assets I have in `/assets` locally aren't publishing to `.com/assets` remotely.

I'm using Siteleaf to deploy my code to an FTP server.

Locally, everything is working at expected. I have the following `_config.yml` set up and assets placed in `/assets` appear immediately in `/_site/assets/`

Oddly when I "Publish Changes" in Siteleaf, those same assets aren't published. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
gems:
- jekyll-assets
assets:
  cache: false
  autowrite: true
  prefix: "/assets"
  digest: false
  assets:
  - "*.png"
  - "*.jpg"
  - "*.svg"
  - "*.otf"
  - "*.ttf"
  - "*.woff"
  - "*.woff2"
  - "*.eot"
  - master.css
  - master.js
  sources:
  - assets/
  - assets/_img
  - assets/_fonts
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being that I was on the trial and not the team plan which enables plugins. N00b move.